# How to separate received bytes

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

How to separate received bytes sent by Bluetooth ?

I read many topics but didn't find what I want. I'm on Android studio 3.3.2 I'm working on Android application that display data received by Bluetooth from a HC-06.
The app received 3 bytes and have to separate them:
1 byte type float will be put in the variable bat
1 byte will be put in the variable tpr
and 1 byte will be put in the variable spd

I was thinking of using this code but I don't know if it's the right code to use and how to adjust it.

```
while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
```

I want to know how to separate them and put them in the different variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the ByteBuffer class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). Put each byte in there. Then use the getFloat method to turn the first bit into a float, and then use the normal get method to get the rest of the bytes

Comment: `    float Fbyte;
    Fbyte = ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[1]).getFloat();
...
}
    public abstract float getFloat();
 `
is this how I should add use the method ?